# btrfs: mismatching generation and generation_v2 found in root item

Tags: boot, btrfs, dmesg

I am seeing this message in `dmesg`:

```
btrfs: mismatching generation and generation_v2 found in root item
```

I found a related question here: [Understanding btrfs dmesg](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/82996/understanding-btrfs-dmesg)

However, unlike that question, I am not seeing any `parent transid verify failed` messages. Should I be concerned about the message I am seeing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens when you go back and forth, mounting a filesystem with new->old->new kernels. It's unimportant, but with Btrfs you should stick to recent kernels anyway.

Comment: Unfortunately, I no longer have any old kernels installed to test. (Really, I just want to know if the message indicates something needs to be fixed or if I can ignore it.)